# Dynamically allocating char pointer pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory, dynamic, allocation

I have created the following test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **messages = NULL;
int messageCount = 0;

void addMessage(char *message) {
    messages = realloc(messages, messageCount * sizeof(char *));
    if(messages == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to realloc");
        return;
    }
    messages[messageCount] = malloc(255 * sizeof(char));
    if(messages[messageCount] == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to alloc");
        return;
    }
    memset(messages[messageCount], '\0', 255);
    strncpy(messages[messageCount], message, 255);
    messageCount++;
}

void listMessages(void) {
    if(messageCount == 0) return;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < messageCount; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", messages[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    addMessage("This");
    listMessages();
    addMessage("is");
    listMessages();
    addMessage("a");
    listMessages();
    addMessage("test");
    listMessages();
    addMessage("for");
    listMessages();
    addMessage("dynamic");
    listMessages();
    addMessage("memory");
    listMessages();
    addMessage("allocation");
    listMessages();
}
```

It is pretty self explanatory as to what I am trying to do.

I get the following output before the program crashes:

```
This

This
is

This
is
a

This
is
```

Note that I am not receiving an "Unable to realloc" or an "Unable to alloc" message.

So why does it crash?

Comment: Where are you incrementing "messageCount"?

Comment: So I know how many messages I have, and thus know how much memory to allocate?

Comment: I meant that you're incrementing it after trying to write to memory allocated based on its value, rather than before....but I see that you've already accepted the answer pointing that out.

Comment: Ah, sorry I thought you said "Why are you..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what your code is doing:

1. Calling addMessage with "This"
2. Calling this function with messageCount = 0: `messages = realloc(messages, messageCount * sizeof(char *));`

And then continually writing into unallocated memory.

So, do a `++messageCount;` at the top of addMessage and you can remove it from the bottom of the function.

Comment: Nice catch! This has been driving me mad; I kept the messageCount++ at the bottome, just did a realloc(messages, (messageCount + 1) * sizeof(char *)) instead. Works a treat.

Answer (score 1):

1. messageCount ++ before you alloc the memory.
2. `messages = realloc(messages, messageCount * sizeof(char *));`

   `if(messages == NULL) {`

   ```
       printf("Unable to realloc");
       return;
   }
   messages[messageCount] = malloc(255 * sizeof(char));//here is wrong `
   ```

You alloc a memory of messageCount, the max index you can use is `messageCount-1!`

You need always use:

```
messages[messageCount-1] = malloc(...)
```

Also other place with `message[messageCount]` should replaced by `messages[messageCount-1]`.

Or, you have a array overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem: in the the first `realloc`, `messageCount` is zero.
`messageCount` should be incremented **before** the call to realloc.

I had written before that `messages` being NULL the first time was the culprit, but it seems that's not really a problem (by @user814064).

Comment: Realloc() operates like this normally when passed a null pointer: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/realloc.html